# Do I need to install aerial wall outlets or is there a wireless solution?

Tags: television

Just bought a new house and realized that everything is great but there's only one aerial socket (rooftop antenna coax connector) and it's on the opposite side of the living room where I want the TV.

I also want a TV in the kitchen and probably some in the bedrooms:  basically, I'd like to be able to put a TV wherever I want conveniently.

So I'm wondering if I need to hire an electrician to install aerial socket outlets in each of the rooms or is there some sort of device I can get to plug into the aerial socket I have now which will increase the TV signal, similar to a wifi repeater or something and then other TVs in the home can use portable antennas.

Comment: What is an "aerial socket"?  Is that an electrical outlet in (or near) the ceiling?

Comment: I would assume the OP is referring to the socket connected to an outside antenna.

Comment: @DoxyLover - yes that is correct - not sure if that's the correct term. There's an antenna on the roof that it hooks up to

Comment: Some [Sony TV models](http://www.trustedreviews.com/Sony-Bravia-KDL-52EX1-52in-LCD-TV_TV_review) had an external wireless tuner.

Comment: @Diskdrive, are you in the US/Canada, or someplace else?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have used in the past is the [HD Home Run](http://www.silicondust.com/).  It is an OTA tuner that outputs to your home WIFI network.  To receive the output, you can use a PC with Windows media player, an XBox or Playstation, or your smart TV if it supports DLNA.

I personally used a PC to receive the signal, and then connected my PC to my TV to view.  The nice part about that is that Windows Media Player has a free program guide for OTA tv, and can act as a DVR.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick Google and found

http://www.marmitek.com/en/product-details/watch/wireless-tv/analogue-tv-anywhere.php

Comment: That seems to be for analog TV, which is no longer broadcast in some countries.

Comment: They have the same thing in digital. Analog may work as it is just transmitting the aerial from your wall into your set top box or your TV with a tuner.

Comment: The one mentioned is just a digital transmission AV sender. You receive what the head end tuner is decoding. It has to resend the complete ATSC broadcast signal to its receiver which must have a tuner in it in order to display independent channels from the head end unit. The operative phrases that give it away are 1) _Watch digital TV far away from the decoder._ 2) _Watch and operate the digital TV channels from your decoder anywhere. ie, it has a wireless control link._

Answer (score 0):

TV is already wireless, just attached to an external antenna.

You have to start with a strong signal as redistribution always degrades the signal, no matter what way you do it.

1. Get a distribution amplifier that will attach to the antenna socket and run coax to all the positions where you want TV reception. Properly designed modern distribution amplifiers will work with the digital signal and not degrade it before amplifying it and passing it on.

In order to wirelessly retransmit, the system will operate up in the 5.8Ghz range so the rebroadcast doesn't interfere with the TV channel reception (think microphone feedback) on your current antenna.

1. If everyone is watching the same thing, wireless A/V redistribution units are made. A master TV decodes the signal and the A/V signal is then fed into the magic box that retransmits it so A/V receivers placed around the house can pick it up. Requires a separate receiver for each TV. The good ones have an IR control link so you can change channels on the master TV.
2. Use a digital wireless cable TV sender system. It requires a transmitter and for each TV set, a receiver with built-in tuner. Each TV set can then watch independent channels. While they were briefly available, they may be hard to find. Must be able to work with ATSC digital signals.